# Comparing student test results

Tags: t-test

Students complete a test at the end of a course. The test conditions are always the same as are the content of the test. Students are given six hours to write a paper on a given topic, the source material is provided for the students to produce their paper. A statistically significant reduction in average test scores has been observed in the last three courses. This reduction has coincided with a change in the person marking the tests. There is a marking guide, however as it is a written test there is a degree of subjectivity in whether the students paper meets the criteria. A working hypothesis is that students attending the last three courses have a lower starting state (inferior knowledge) compared with students from previous courses.
The number of students attending each course is between 13 and 24. The average score for the all previous five courses is 76% with a Std Dev of 4.97, 7.6, 5.36, 5.42 respectively. The last three courses had an average score of 65%, 66%, and 59%. With a std dev of 9.18, 8.71, and 12.51 respectively.

Is there a way to test the working hypotheses, perhaps assuming a lower starting state of say 0.5 compared with previous students? Is there any way to test the possibility of inconsistent marking given the students are always selected randomly and the test conditions have remained the same?

Comment: Even with detailed info on student scores, I see no way to separate the grading effect from the student preparation effect. Recent lower scores and higher SDs could be a clue to either change. // But info is incomplete: You say there are five early tests, but give only four SD's. You say course sizes vary btw 13 and 24. You give a composite avg score for earlier five, but course averages for the last three. With such info it is difficult to determine whether differences in scores are significant.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear: the *only* thing your data establish about average scores is that they have declined.  You have no basis to attribute that decline to any particular factor, whether it be the students, the graders, the quality of the courses they took, increases in global temperatures, or the appearance of more US movies based on comic books.  There is, however, some evidence of greater *variability* in test scores; but again, you have no information to allow you to attribute that change to anything.

Comment: I should have been more clear. The fifth SD is 3.84 (sorry for missing it out). There is no composite mean, the first five courses averaged 76% each.

Comment: Can I treat the first five courses and the latter three courses as two sample populations. if so comparison of them shows the latter three courses  have a statically significant difference in both the mean and variance (using an T-test and F-test). Given the course and test contents are unchanged does this suggest a different marking standard rather than lower student ability? Should I conduct an ANOVA to ensure similarity amongst two populations